# Xcode Other Swift Flags not working with framework

Tags: swift, xcode

Now I have an iPhone app and planning to come up with a separate iPad app. Lots of codes from the iPhone are to be re-used in the iPad app.

So I have made that common code to be in a framework so that both iPhone and iPad apps will embed it. Now for my iPhone app, I have 2 targets, UAT and Prod. And all along I use the Other Swift Flag in Build Settings to distinguish them.

The problem now is that those flags do not work any more.

[image]

It just skips my UAT block

```
#if UAT

#elseif

#endif
```

Then I tried putting "-DUAT" in my framework target and it works!

[image]

But I only intend to only have 1 target for this to all iPhone targets.
How to make this work that the flags should only come from the app targets and not from the framework?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I ran into the exact same issue.

Comment: You should keep the flag on your project and init your framework with settings based on that flag.